# SQL Server switching live database

Tags: sql-server, database

A client has one of my company's applications which points to a specific database and tables within the database on their server.  We need to update the data several times a day.  We don't want to update the tables that the users are looking at in live sessions.  We want to refresh the data on the side and then flip which database/tables the users are accessing.

What is the accepted way of doing this?  Do we have two databases and rename the databases?  Do we put the data into separate tables, then rename the tables?  Are there other approaches that we can take?

Comment: Are the users accessing reports via procedures?

Comment: You're not worried about data being entered in database 1 while you are updating database 2? Is this read-only data?

Comment: Partition switching or change to _Read Committed Snapshot Isolation_ http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/. Partition switching requires fiddling about with your load process. Read Committed Snapshot Isolation just requires that you use transactions and is much simpler.

Comment: Nick -- Committed Snapshot Isolation sounds interesting as the data tables being updated are fairly isolated.  The data in one table does not get mixed up with data from another in displayed reports.  If I knew that I could update a table or two at a time as a standalone process then have the transaction update just those tables, this might be good enough for what I want to achieve.

Comment: It's a solid foundation for a system that has simultaneous reads and writes of the same data, but they shouldn't interrupt each other.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're saying: if the user is on a screen you don't want the screen updating with new information while they're viewing it, only update when they pull a new screen after the new data has been loaded? Correct me if I'm wrong. And Mike's question is also a good one, how is this data being fed to the users? Possibly there's a way to pause that or something while the new data is being loaded. There are more elegant ways to load data like possibly partitioning the table, using a staging table, replication, have the users view snapshots, etc. But we need to know what you mean by 'live sessions'.

Edit: with the additional information you've given me, partition switching *could* be the answer. The process takes virtually no time, it just changes the pointers from the old records to the new ones. Only issue is you have to partition on something patitionable, like a date or timestamp, to differentiate old and new data. It's also an Enterprise-Edition feature and I'm not sure what version you're running.

Possibly a better thing to look at is Read Committed Snapshot Isolation. It will ensure that your users only look at the new data after it's committed; it provides a transaction-level consistent view of the data and has minimal concurrency issues, though there is more overhead in TempDB. Here are some resources for more research:

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/snapshot-isolation-level-in-sql-server-what-why-and-how-part-1.html
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: The data is pulled back in discrete chunks.  The user does not look at forms where that data is constantly updated.  They ask for a set of data, it is retrieved and presented.  Then in a few minutes they ask for another set of data. The data comes from raw tables, no stored procedures or the like.  But the user can be using the program during the time period when the data is being updated.  Right now, we are updating the tables as the users are requesting the data. A data request can hit the database in an unstable moment and not return data.  I am trying to avoid this.

Comment: I know even with partitioning, a user just might ask for the data when the switch is in progress.  But this would be less likely to happen than what is currently done where the update process can take 20 to 30 minutes.  The update process deals with one table (of 20) at a time.  So hopefully only that table's data will look odd.  But I still am looking for something cleaner.

Comment: Normal record locking in SQL Server stops any 'unstable moments'. Either the record is complete or not. Problems happen when you sprinkle `WITH (NOLOCK)` fairy dust through your code. Then you open yourself up to errors. Normal record locking introduces 'contention' though. So do you have a problem with contention (deadlocks, performance issues), or do you have a problem with consistency (corrupt data, which can only be introduced with `NOLOCK`)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you have provided, I believe your best bet would be partition switching. I've included a couple links for you to check out because it's much easier to direct you to a source that already explains it well.  There are several approaches with partition switching you can take.

Links: [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191160(v=sql.105).aspx) and [Catherin Wilhelmsen blog](http://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2015/04/19/table-partitioning-in-sql-server-partition-switching/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The question details are a little vague so to clarify:

What is a live session? Is it a session in the application itself (with app code managing it's own connections to the database) or is it a low level connection per user/session situation? Are users just running reports or active reading/writing from the database during the session? When is a session over and how do you know?

Some options:

1) Pull all the data into the client for the entire session.

2) Use read committed or partitions as mentioned in other answers (however requires careful setup for your queries and increases requirements for the database)

3) Use replica database for all queries, pause/resume replication when necessary (updating data should be faster than your process but it still might take a while depending on volume and complexity)

4) Use replica database and automate a backup/restore from the master (this might be the quickest depending on the overall size of your database)

5) Use multiple replica databases with replication or backup/restore and then switch the connection string (this allows you to update the master constantly and then update a replica and switch over at a certain predictable time)